# jquery remove element and also list selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list that when the user selects an item it builds an `li` element on the fly, when the users clicks the `li` element, the `li` is removed. Below is the code that I currently have,

The below adds the li on select of an option

`$('#sectors').change(function(e){

    $('#selected_sectors').empty();

    $(this).find(':selected').each(function(i,e

         {$('#selected_sectors').append($('<li>').text($(e).val()));
            });
        });`

The below removes the generated li

`$('ul#selected_sectors li').live('click', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow').remove();
        $('#selected_sectors').val($(this).text()).attr('selected', false);
    });`

What I am wanting is when an `li` is removed the select option with the same value as the li's text is also unselected?

Answer (score 0):

You can select options based upon value like the following:

```
$("#sectors").val("0")
```

Or you can select based upon first option element

```
$("#sectors option").first().attr("selected", "selected");
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/egLsJ/)